# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel show empty content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented a twitter bootstrap 3 carousel into my page but have run into an issue with it. After sliding content showing blank.

```
<!-- CAROUSEL -->
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="background-color:#B0A7A1 solid 1px;">

                          <!-- INDICATORS -->
                          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                          </ol>
                          <!-- INDICATORS END -->

                          <!-- CAROUSEL INNER CONTENT -->
                          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                            <!-- ITEM 1 -->
                            <div class="active item">
                              <img src="images/slider-bg.png">
                              <div class="container">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                  <h3 style="margin: 5px 0;">Senior Account Officers</h3>
                                  <h5>Description</h5>
                                  <h5 class="text-justify">If you're viewing this page via a the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</h5>
                                  <p><a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="#">Read More</a></p>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- ITEM 1 -->

                            <!-- ITEM 2 -->
                            <div class="item">
                              <img src="images/slider-bg.png">
                              <div class="container">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                  <h3 style="margin: 5px 0;">Felcon India required Experienced CA Officer</h3>
                                  <h5>Description</h5>
                                  <h5 class="text-justify">If you're viewing this page via a the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</h5>
                                  <p><a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="#">Read More</a></p>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- ITEM 2 -->

                            <!-- ITEM 3 -->
                            <div class="item">
                              <img src="images/slider-bg.png">
                              <div class="container">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                  <h3 style="margin: 5px 0;">Ca Fresher Internship Program</h3>
                                  <h5>Description</h5>
                                  <h5 class="text-justify" >If you're viewing this page via a the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</h5>
                                  <p><a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="#">Read More</a></p>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- ITEM 3 -->

                          </div>
                          <!-- CAROUSEL INNER CONTENT END -->
                    </div>
                <!-- CAROUSEL END HERE -->
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have initialized the bootstrap .js file.

Comment: after complete 3 slider it will display none;

Comment: Can you reproduce it with a demo? I tried to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mvofvfps/) this and it is working properly.